# How can I become an invalid target for spells that target humanoids?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, druid, targeting

One of my players is a druid who would like to be able to change their creature type so that they become an invalid target against spells that target humanoids.  First party WotC content (including UA) is preferred, though items from previous editions are also acceptable that can be supported by gameplay in 5e.

The option for using their wildshape to turn into a Beast is an obvious option, as is using spells like polymorph, but I'm looking for mechanics beyond those.

A spell scroll of Nystul's Mystical Aura in D&D5e is the closest I've found so far by allowing the target's creature type to be changed for divination spells, but the target is still physically its original type and may still be valid against spells targeting humanoids. Changing to a plant creature type would be ideal in this situation to further some roleplaying aims, though some "minor" bookkeeping changes like vulnerability to fire are also okay.

Comment: They should just have the creature type Plant; nothing else would change. Otherwise true polymorph would work to turn them into another creature with that type.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's mostly a "flavor-appropriate" way to be able to avoid charm person or similar effects that specifically target humanoids, though potentially making tradeoffs like vulnerability to fire and poison.

Comment: Related (regarding changing a PC's type to something else, fey in this case): [What are the mechanical consequences of a Centaur's Fey trait?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136750/35259)

Comment: Also, regarding vulnerability to poison, don't druids become immune to poison at level 10 or so? Something to bear in mind with regards to tradeoffs...

Comment: @NautArch the reason for wanting to be able to shift to plant-types without changing much else is twofold: to avoid some of the overhead with figuring out proficiency bonuses and the like when wild-shaping (so everything would be the same except now they are type plant), and to provide some additional roleplaying opportunities for the druid.

Comment: If you're excluding wild shape because it involves too many other changes to your stats, does that imply that you're looking for options that change _only_ your creature type?

Comment: @MarkWells yes, that has been specified in the comments. I'm looking for things beyond just Wild Shape and variants of Polymorph.

Answer (score 12):

## Spells that have you assume something else's statistics are your best bet.

Since you're discarding the Druid's **[Wild Shape](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Classes:Druid#toc_6)**, other options include spells like [Polymorph](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Polymorph), Animal Shapes, Shape Change, Mass Polymorph, or True Polymorph. The simulacrum spells creates a construct clone of yourself, though it's not exactly *you* who becomes immune to humanoid-targeting spells. As far as I can tell, there are no items that change your typing.

**Hide your creature type.** [Nystul's Magic Aura](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/nystuls-magic-aura) can mask what your type is to abilities like Divine Sense, as can the Ring of Mind Shielding.

If you find a way to change your race (if you haven't made the character yet, or you get a Wish), consider the [Centaur](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136750/what-are-the-mechanical-consequences-of-a-centaurs-fey-trait) race (a fey).

To avoid being targeted by spells, you can rely on **cover** (to avoid being targeted by any spell that requires line-of-effect), **hide** from line of sight (many spells require seeing the target), [Globe of Invulnerability](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Globe%20of%20Invulnerability#content) (for spells below 5th level), divination-foiling spells (Mind Blank, Sequester, Nondetection, Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum), or items that give you an edge against spells (like [Robe of the Archmagi](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Robe%20of%20the%20Archmagi#content)).

Other (out of the box) solutions include becoming undead: killing yourself to be resurrected as a [Zombie](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Animate%20Dead), becoming a [Lich](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwCk_HKsPM8) (if you dip in Wizard), or a [Vampire](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Vampire#content).

Comment: Out of the box solutions, naturally, are the ones that first require that you get put into a box.

Comment: I feel like becoming a Zombie removes the "I" part of the equation (as in the questioner's "How can ***I*** become an invalid target for spells that target humanoids?"). There is a Zombie. It's not *you* anymore. Lich and Vampire are at least intelligent (though in the vampire case, it's probably not the *same* personality), but Zombies lack any discernable personality at all. You could just die and be burned to ashes to become an invalid target for most such spells, but that doesn't really mean you succeeded.